Call an async method in VB6
I've made a dll in VB.NET (.NET Framework 4.8).
This dll uses the HttpClient.GetAsync method, as you can see.
All go well if I call this dll in a .NET app.
When I build the dll, create the tlb and call the method in VB6 or VBA, the GetAsync method throw an exception: "one or more errors have occurred".
How can I solve this?
I tried the Await keyword, but doesn't work.
Private Function CallServer(domain As String) As String
    Dim data As String

    Using client As New HttpClient()
        Try
            Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = client.GetAsync(domain).GetAwaiter.GetResult
            If response.IsSuccessStatusCode Then
                data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
            Else
                data = "HTTPS Request Error: " & response.StatusCode.ToString()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            data = "HTTPS Request Error: " & ex.Message
        End Try
    End Using

    Return data
End Function

Exception Type: System.AggregateException
StackTrace:
    in System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
       in System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
       in System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
       in ActivationSystem.HttpClientManager.CallServer(String action)

I managed the aggregateException and the only exception in it is:
An error occurred while sending the request
without a stacktrace.
Edit:
I find a thing. if I use Albert D. Kallal example to call google, also in HTTPS protocol, all go well, but if I call our domain the error "An error occurred while sending the request." appear. so i think that is not a code problem, but a domain problem. But now the question is: why in .net all go well (example and my code, google or our domain), and in vba no?

You need to determine what the one or more errors are. You should catch the specific type of exception that's thrown, not just the base Exception, and it will probably have a collection property that contains data about the specific errors that occurred.

I edit the message, adding the exceptiontype and stacktrace info.

the GetAsync method throw an exception - how do you know? As you are getting an aggregate exception, it looks like it's ReadAsStringAsync().Result that throws it. If you are doing this bad thing anyway, why use .GetAwaiter().GetResult() in one place and .Result in another?

I know is the GetASync because I put switches in my code, that I don't put here for simplicity.
The code never go in the   If response.IsSuccessStatusCode Then

Did you look at the InnerException of the aggregate exception? There may be one or more other exceptions there with more details.

I solved the problem with HTTPWEBRequest methods, insted of HTTPClient. Here below the correct code:
Function CallServer(domain As String) As String
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = DirectCast(3072, SecurityProtocolType)
    ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 9999
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = New Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AddressOf AcceptAllCertifications)
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(domain), HttpWebRequest)
    Using response As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        Using stream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
            Using reader As New StreamReader(stream)
                Return reader.ReadToEnd()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Function

Private Function AcceptAllCertifications(sender As Object, certification As System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate, chain As System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain, sslPolicyErrors As Security.SslPolicyErrors) As Boolean
    Return True
End Function

I don't know yet why HTTPClient don't work with VB6/VBA

Hum, you have to use non async here, since I don't believe that COM objects support as such.
However, say this code in vb.net (a standard .net framework class).
Imports System.Net.Http
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Threading
<ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)>
Public Class WebCallCOM

    Public Function CallServer(domain As String) As String

        Dim data As String
        Using client As New HttpClient()
            Try
                Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = client.GetAsync(domain).GetAwaiter.GetResult
                If response.IsSuccessStatusCode Then
                    data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
                Else
                    data = "HTTPS Request Error: " & response.StatusCode.ToString()
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                data = "HTTPS Request Error: " & ex.Message
            End Try
        End Using
        Return data
    End Function

So, build the above.
Now, in say Access VBA, this works fine:
Sub WebLoaderTest()

    Dim cWeb As New WebCallCOM.WebCallCOM
    
    Dim sURL As String
    sURL = "https://Google.ca"
    Dim sResult As String
    
    sResult = cWeb.CallServer(sURL)
    
    Debug.Print sResult
        

End Sub

So, since the vb.net code is not marked as "async", then the above works for me without error.
So, as long as that vb.net routine is not marked as "async", then it should wait, and work.
You might be able to start a whole new thread in vb.net, perhaps use a .join for the new thread (not a task) to complete, and use that.
However, so far, the above posted code does work just fine when used as a COM object say from VBA.

read my complete answer below

Solved the problem: for your class I had to registeer the dll as 32bit, not 64. the problem in my class is the same as before.

Though COM does not support async directly, why couldn't it make an async call internally?

Sure, the whole idea is to have a public sub routine that is NOT async, but calls a async routine. If you can show the readers how to tag a sub as not async, but calls a async then you get a gold seal award here. The WHOLE issue is that you can't really have a non async routine call a async routine. However, if there is a way, then that would help boatloads. I simply don't know of a simple and valid way to have a vb.net routine that is not marked as async to call a async routine. If that could be done, then we expose to com the non async public sub in vb.net which then can be called from VBA

Albert D. Kallal, my answer was deleted, I modify the original post...
